# Google Data Studio: 2 different data sources, but same data set and same custom field -> 2 different results for summary row. Can someone explain why?

Tags: looker-studio

I have this data set from two different data sources:

| Date | Site Name | Cost | Clicks |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10.05.2022 | SevenOne Connected TV Netzwerk | 573,1656 | 0 |
| 10.05.2022 | Ad Alliance Channel Food | 159,04728 | 21 |
| 12.05.2022 | SevenOne Connected TV Netzwerk | 670,17342 | 0 |
| 12.05.2022 | Ad Alliance Channel Food | 115,34005 | 10 |
| 11.05.2022 | SevenOne Connected TV Netzwerk | 607,06569 | 0 |
| 11.05.2022 | Ad Alliance Channel Food | 196,40229 | 28 |

One data source is Funnel.io, it is something like Supermetrics: It collects data from several marketing platforms via APIs. From there I import them to Google Data Studio.

The other data source is Google Sheets where I've entered the same dataset.

In Data Studio, I've created the same custom field for both data sets:

'Cost (with condition)'

```
if(Clicks>0,Cost,NULL)
```

The table with Google Sheets as data source shows as summary row:

| Clicks | Cost | Cost (with condition) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 59 | 2.321,19 € | 470,79€ |

The table with Funnel.io as data source shows as summary row:

| Clicks | Cost | Cost (with condition) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 59 | 2.321,19 € | 2.321,19 € |

Apparently, the lower table seems to sum up 'Cost (with condition)' dfferently: The condition doesn't seem to work for the summary row and I don't know why! Can somebody explain? I want the lower table to show the same results as the upper one.

Here's the Data Studio report: https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/f3f74b39-5e9c-4396-97f9-cbc2a2395158

Help is greatly appreciated!